# Matar una ejecución(Kill Task) desde C#

Tags: c#

Necesito cerrar una aplicación externa en ejecución desde C#, un `TaskKill`, 
¿cómo puedo hacerlo? o, ¿hay qué abrir un comando de consola y ejecutarlo?

En mi caso mi aplicación abre un archivo excel y luego despues de hacer algunas cosas lo tiene que cerrar.

Comment: La respuesta del usuario JuanK puede servirle, pero, si desea cerrar correctamente el archivo Excel que esté manipulando, le sugiero [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código que esté usando para manipular el Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Con algo como esto bastará:

```
foreach ( Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")) {
    try {
        p.Kill();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Juan, sé que el OP indica matar el proceso, pero, ¿sería lo correcto? Es decir, si estás abriendo un archivo lo ideal sería hacer un `dispose` del espacio de memoria que ocupa ese proceso.

Comment: No, en este caso es lo correcto. Una aproximación más decente puede ser llamar a excel usando los Office interop Assemblies y desde allí luego cerrarlo, pero dado que no hay responsabilidad en los contenidos del archivo una vez abierto excel, estaríamos hablando de over engineering. Incluso recuerdo que los interop assemblies no te dejan cerrar la instancia de excel, lo cual siempre fue un problema... tal vez las últimas versiones pero no lo creo.

Comment: Pareciera que no hay responsabilidad pero es algo que no sabemos. Así como está formulada la pregunta realmente me parece un tanto amplia. Es posible que al usar Interop exista una solucion sobrada, aunque nunca está de más asegurar la mejor solución. Por cierto, un `try` sin `catch` marcaría un error ;)

Comment: De la responsabilidad lo digo porque una vez Excel es el que está manipulando el archivo ya se sale del control del programador desde el punto de vista del framework. Lo del try {} catch, por eso no había un  } sino puntos suspensivos... Pero 'alguien' lo editó jajaja